What characters need escaping in bcp?
I'm loading some large data-sets using bcp, and I'm somewhat confused by what, if anything, I need to escape in the data.
According to the docs:

The characters <, >, |, &, and ^ are special command shell characters, and they must be preceded by the escape character (^), or enclosed in quotation marks when used in String

However, I am not finding this to be the case, as < > | & ^ " all load without issues and with no escaping. What have I misunderstood? What, if anything, really does need escaping?
Here's my bcp command:
bcp proton..trg_patient_571 in trg_patient_571.txt -c -t~, -r~\n -Slocalhost -T

And, just to clarify, I'm talking about the content of my bcp data-file (e.g. trg_patient_571.txt), not the command line.

You're not using any of those characters on the command line. Are they in your text file? That's not the same thing.

For example, if you have a file called Bad & Silly File Name.txt then you may need to escape the &.

Ah, okay. So what, if anything, do I need to escape in the text file?

Well you can't import the end-of-field or end-of-row characters by definition, unless you use the FORMAT=CSV option and they are properly escaped using quotes.
